# How to capture all characters in binary string without python interpreting it

Tags: python, regex, struct

Here is how I reproduce the problem:

Create a log file called 'temp.log' and paste this line into it

```
DEBUG: packetReceived '\x61\x62\x63'
```

I want to have a script which will read the line from the log file and decode the binary string part ('\x61\x62\x63').  For the decoding, I am using struct, so:

```
struct.unpack('BBB', '\x61\x62\x63')
```

Should give me

```
(97, 98, 99)
```

Here is the script which I am using

```
import re
import struct
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
    packet = re.compile(r"packetReceived \'(.*)\'").search(line).group(1)

    # packet is the string r'\x61\x62\x63'
    assert(len(packet), 12)

    # this works ok (returns (97, 98, 99))
    struct.unpack('BBB', '\x61\x62\x63')

    # this fails because packet is interpreted as r'\\x61\\x62\x63'
    struct.unpack('BBB', packet)
```

I run the script using temp.log as the argument to the script.

Hopefully the comments highlight my problem.  How can I get the variable packet to be interpreted as '\x61\x62\x63' ??

ASIDE:  On the first edit of this question,  I assumed that reading the line from the file was the same as this:
line = "DEBUG: packetReceived '\x61\x62\x63'"
which made packet == 'abc'

however it is actually the same as this (using rawstring)
line = r"DEBUG: packetReceived '\x61\x62\x63'"

Comment: Are you sure you received twelve characters and not just three that were represented as twelve?

Comment: @johnsyweb There were 12 characters.  The DEBUG statement which I attached is actually a copy/paste from the text file.

Comment: Have you sniffed what is being sent on-the-wire?

Comment: @johnsyweb:  I havn't tried to snif the packets because what I am really trying to do here is take a string representation of the packet from the log file and decode it.  When I just copy/paste the string from the log file, decoding works fine.  My real problem is reading the string representation into a variable and using this in the decoder.  I updated the question after getting some useful tips from feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in your question, packet **is** equal to `'\x61\x62\x63'`. Its len is 12 bytes, neither 15 nor 3 bytes.

What confuses you, is that ipython (which I understand you are using) and the python interpreter display values using the `repr()` call, which tries to format values as they would be in your code. Since backslashes are special in Python string constants, `repr()` displays them duplicated, as they would be in Python code.

This might be of help:

```
for char in packet:
    print("%5d %2s %2r" % (ord(char), char, char))
```

Count your characters and see how they are printed. First column displays the ordinal value of the character, second column has the character itself, third column has the `repr` of the character.

#### EDIT

Change the last line:

```
struct.unpack('BBB', packet)
```

to:

```
struct.unpack('BBB', packet.decode('string_escape'))
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification on repr in ipython.  I updated the question with a script.  I'm hoping that someone can see what I'm doing wrong from this.

Comment: @ephesian: can you try again with my suggestion?

Comment: dude, thank you so much!  This is a great solution! up until now, I didn't know anything about the codecs.

Answer (score 5):

Python doesn't interpret strings that you pass to regular expressions. The escape sequences were most likely interpreted earlier, when you defined variable `line`. This works correctly for example:

```
line = r"DEBUG: packetReceived '\x61\x62\x63'"
print re.compile(r"packetReceived '(.*)'").search(line).group(1)
```

It prints `\x61\x62\x63`.

Comment: OK, I see better now (I think).  So the problem is actually when I do the "for line in f" part of the code.  I need some way to make line not interpret the escape sequences.

Comment: @ephesian: File reading normally shouldn't interpret escape sequences either. You won't come around debugging your code (and be it with `print` statments) to find out where exactly that happens because I cannot guess it.

Comment: Thanks. You are quite correct.  I realised that I made a mistake trying to debug this by manually setting line (and not using rawstring).  I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.compile(r"packetReceived '(.*)'").search(r"DEBUG: packetReceived '\x61\x62\x63'").group(1)
'\\x61\\x62\\x63'
```

Nope, that line is not where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you are receiving twelve characters and not just three represented as twelve, it may be just the printing of the string that is causing you grief.

Compare:

```
>> print '\x61\x62\x63'
abc
>>> print r'\x61\x62\x63'
\x61\x62\x63
```

My 50c is on you actually receiving three characters and them being printed like this:

```
>>> print ''.join('\\x%02x' % ord(c) for c in 'abc')
\x61\x62\x63
```